# RS256 JSON web token generator for firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement firebase authentication using custom JWT and I could not find any RS256 JWT token generator for firebase.

I have tried this
https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-generation
(in tutorial it shows it has option for rs256 but got error in console  `Uncaught init failed:not supported argument`)

and in this

http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html (this is not the perfect format desired for firebase)

Please suggest me any good way using simple JavaScript

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK?

Comment: I didn't want any node dependencies. I want to implement it in plain JS

Comment: Just make sure you're not minting custom JWTs in a client app. That's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Look at here for detail informations

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0

Install Firebase Admin SDK

```
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Generate Private Key (serviceAccountKey.json):

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk

Code

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com"
});
```